# Is there a way to move the sculpt tools (grab tool for example) away or towards the user?

Tags: sculpting

I am sculpting some features and I want to make some precise sculpting moves. With the grab tool, I would like to grab a part of the mesh and move it "away" from me, without any lateral movement of mesh. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You could activate Symmetry/Lock panel to lock brush effect by any of those axes, if by Y then locking X and Z. Though this won't really work if object / surface is not oriented along global axes.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Consider

- Quad View so you are seeing both front and side views.  Or you can open 2 edit windows to get the exact views you need by rotation of view.
- Sculpt Draw Brush with Add selected as depicted in the image above.
- Click in the same place on mesh.  No lateral movement is needed.
- To emphasize you are only clicking an area with no movement of cursor.  The area grows toward you the viewer, which is difficult to see.  You see the growth in the profile view. You are creating a protrusion directly growing towards you.  You may click in Top Ortho and see growth in Right Ortho.  Create change in one view and see it in another view.

Comment: That doesn't quite work for my situation. The main challenge is that the surface I want to sculpt is flat, so I can't grab the correct location in side view, and in an angled view I don't have precise control over what direction I am pulling/pusing in.

Comment: Please read above the added information.  It is useful for me.  I think when you experiment it will be useful for you.

Comment: The flatness of view presents no problem for the discussion above.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you mean. I'm not sure how it behaves for you, but when you use the grab tool in quad view, do all the views update in real time? Because they don't for me, only when I finish my action in one of the views.

Comment: I clicked with no motion. On release the other views updated.  I just peeked in.  I wont see any messages for 12 hours.